# Fixing conflict in Git

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I am using Github for manipulating files through a branch, on the way I did not pull the changes from a tsv file from the master to my branch and I updated a file in this format that eliminated the work done by the master and appears like a new file. This is causing conflicts and avoiding the automatically merge. I want to know how can I solve this issue such that I can merge my files into the master branch with zero conflicts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to just replace the specific TSV file which you accidentally modified with the version coming from the upstream, you may use:

```
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/some/file.tsv
```

This assumes that the branch on which you are working is `master`, and the file's path is `path/to/some/file.tsv`.  You may change these values to match your actual setup.

Comment: I am working in a branch of master and I uploaded a file using Github, so in this case, your suggestion could work also? If not, what would be different? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Whether your Git provider be GitHub, Bitbucket, or something else, doesn't really matter or change my answer.  I am simply suggesting that you replace the TSV file with the version from the upstream.